# How to get selected value and and id from dropdownlist in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I make my httppost call, i need to get the selected value and the id of a random number of dropdownlists in my view. The number of dropdownlists is random because they are created dynamically based on the selected value of another dropdownlist.
Example:
in dropdownlist 1 I select bmw. Then 3 dropdownlists are created, so the user can give each carmodel a rate value. Each dropdownlist has id= the model of the car and the options you can select is 1,2 and 3. If there was 4 carmodels of bmw, the options would then be 1,2,3 and 4 and so on...
When I make the httppost call, how do I in the controller run through all the dynammically created dropdownlist and check the value and id?

EDIT:
The controller of my index view:

```
public class BookingPensionController : Controller
{
    private DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
    EditBookingPensionViewModel objViewModel;
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        objViewModel = new EditBookingPensionViewModel
        {
            Booking = new Booking { BookingStartDate = DateTime.Today, BookingEndDate =  DateTime.Today, DateOfBooking = DateTime.Now }
        };
        objViewModel.deliveryTypes = new List<string>();
        int id = int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString());
        SelectList list;
        try
        {
            var deliverytypes = from d in db.DeliveryTypes
                                where d.Pension_ID == id
                                select d;
            foreach (DeliveryType item in deliverytypes)
            {
                objViewModel.deliveryTypes.Add(item.Titel);
            }
            ViewData["DeliveryTypes"] = objViewModel.deliveryTypes;

            objViewModel.customersToPension = new List<SelectListItem>();
            objViewModel.customersToPension = GetCustomersToPension(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        int PensionId = int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString());
        objViewModel.CustomerValue = GetCustomersToPension(PensionId);

        return View(objViewModel);
    }
```

My Index view:

```
@model HundePensionBooking.ViewModels.EditBookingPensionViewModel
//Some code...
//And my script that retreives the customerinfo and creates the dropdownlists
$("#ddlCustomerId").change(function () {

         var id = $("#ddlCustomerId").val();
         getCustomerInfo(id);
         $('#customerinfo').load("@Url.Action("CustomerInfo", "BookingPension")");

         var ddlsource = "#ddlCustomerId";
         var ddltarget = "#ddlDogId";
         $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Dogs_SelectedCustomer")', { CustomerId: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {


             $(ddltarget).empty();
             $("#tblRooms tr:gt(0)").remove();
             $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                 createDynamicTable($("#tblRooms"), optionData.Text, data.length);
             });
         });
     });
 });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function createDynamicTable(tbody, value, count) {
         if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1) return;

             var trow = $("<tr>");
                 var cellText = value
                     var option;
                     $('<th scope="row" abbr="Model" class="spec">')
                        .addClass("tableCell")
                        .text(cellText)
                        .appendTo(trow);

                     var ddlselectroom = '<td class="spectd"><select class="selectbox" id=' + value + '>';
                     for (var d = 1; d <= count; d++) {
                         ddlselectroom += '<option value="' + d + '">Bur nr. ' + d + '</option>';
                     }

                     ddlselectroom += '</select></td>';
                     $(ddlselectroom).appendTo(trow);
             trow.appendTo(tbody);
     }
```

```
//Some more code...
//And then the table which gets populated with the random number of dropdownlists:
<table id="tblRooms" width="100%">
    <tr>
</tr>
    </table>
```

The Viewmodel looks like this:

```
    public class EditBookingPensionViewModel
{
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> customerList { get; set; }
    public List<string> deliveryTypes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> customersToPension { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public CustomerInfoModel CustomerInfo { get; set; }
```

My partialview with the customerinfo looks like this:

```
@model HundePensionBooking.Models.Customer
```

So when I make the httppost call

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

I need to get all the data down to my database. Im not sure on how to do that but I assume I have to do it with my Create method in the controller class

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EditBookingPensionViewModel model)
    {
        //SaveCustomer... From the CustomerInfo partialview
        //SaveBooking...From Index view
        //Save all the data from all the dropdownlists... from index view
    }
```

Comment: what is in the FormCollection on the post?

Comment: Please post the code you have now, it will be easier for us to see the problem.

Comment: Added som code... Just say if you need more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a hidden field of counter,  when you submit, get value of counter then loop from 1 to value of counter and request optionname + counter.  jquery should be used to set the value of counter.

Comment: Sounds interesting... I should be able to add the hidden field and make the jquery, but im a little unsure of how to request the optionname?

Comment: use formcollection form   as well as your modelname  model    then you can simply do request[numberinloop];

Comment: i always find that the less code the better, try using http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/  and maybe possibly getting rid of tables all together as you dont need em really just some good css and you can get the same layout but half the code.  when you pick a model from the dropdown   just a thought

Comment: Thanks. Will rethink my setup and try and make it a little better :) Will take a look at the link you suggested.